# Using JavaScript to wrap the HTML5 video element breaks video player in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, html, video

I am using JavaScript to wrap an HTML5 video player in a div for styling purposes. If the mark-up exists when the page loads, the player functions as it should. However if I apply the wrapper dynamically with JavaScript, the player goes black and its controls are inaccessible. I have tested applying various elements as wrappers, and it seems to happen with any block level element, but not inline elements. I can't find any documentation on this bug or others who have encountered it via Google. Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: HTML and JS will be required so we can understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I can repo it, but don't have a fix. Doing anything to the video that deals with parents or positioning seems to break it: reparenting accessing offset* properties, etc.
jQuery has a bug thread about it, marked "can't fix": http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8015

Answer (score 0):

I see this was posted a long time ago & I ran into a similar issue.

When a video is reparented (like it would be if you used a solution like [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), it reverts to 00:00 and pauses.  Once reparented, you should be able to directly access the video via JS & invoke the play() method to get it started again.